# Аналог оператора C# \n для строки в HTML &#10; &#13; не отрабатывает

Tags: html, django, строки

Сайт на Django 3.2, Visual Studio 2019.
Необходимо перенести текст описания ссылки - текстовой строки в коде HTML.
Существуют специальные коды HTML &#10 ; &#13 ; для окончания строки и перевода каретки.
Их применение не даёт нужного результата.
< p >, < br >, < div > - действуют за рамками строки. Потому создаются две разные ссылки с одинаковым содержанием, что нежелательно (прописано поведение при :hover).
Т.е. необходим аналог "\n" для языков C#/C++/C, который обрабатывается внутри строки в коде HTML.

```
{% extends "/layout.html" %}<!--♕-->{% block content %}<div class="Jambotron">
<h1>Добро пожаловать!</h1>
<p class="lead">Text1!&#10;&#13;Text2.</p>
<a href="link">Text3.&#10;&#13;Text4.</a></div>{% endblock %}
```

Пример: cпец коды не отработали, как задумывалось

[image: Пример: cпец коды не отработали, как задумывалось]

Comment: ``Text3.<br>Text4.`` должно работать. Почему не работает-то?

Comment: Чем не угодил `<br>`?

Comment: Да, работает. Вставил <br> прямо в описание, и работает как нужно. Спасибо. Не ожидал, что и внутри строки будет работать обычный тег... Но специальные символы не работают, а должны. Хотелось бы понять на будущее, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML несколько пробелов по умолчанию сворачиваются в один пробел. Это отличная "фича", так как она позволяет вам писать разметку с удобочитаемыми отступами и т. д.

Однако вы можете управлять этим поведением с помощью свойства CSS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Для сохранения специальных пробелов вы можете использовать `white-space: normal;`

```
p {
white-space: normal;
}

a {
white-space: normal;
}
```

После дополнения к стилю - спец коды начинают работать

```
<p class="lead">Text1!&#10;&#13;Text2.</p>
<a href="link">Text3.&#10;&#13;Text4.</a>
```

(Спасибо lupz)